# How can I go to the top of Aiguille du Midi in France?

Tags: public-transport, france, sightseeing, alps

I want to visit the new [Step into the Void](http://news.yahoo.com/glass-bottom-viewing-platform-opens-alps-172816552.html) glass cube on the top of Aiguille du Midi. Are there any transport such as cable car? How much would it cost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Chamonix website](http://www.chamonix.com/aiguille-du-midi,80,en.html#tarifs), there is a cable car operating from Chamonix to Aiguille du Midi almost all year around (except for 11/4-12/20). The return-trip would cost you 55 euro's.